# Toolbar transparent with navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I am trying to make toolbar transparent with navigation drawer. It is working fine til api<21, But above api 21 toolbar is not transparent. I have already added theme to v-21 style folder as well. Adding theme as well as image.
[image: Api < 21]

[image: Api > 21]

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Moreover, i have created a background selector for toolbar as well in which colors are transparent

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.mayank.tracar.activties.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
         />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it by changing these things in my code. Hope it will help someone else as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.mayank.tracar.activties.MainActivity">



<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
     />



 <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If remove AppBarLayout then your toolbar goes behind the include layout, so to solve this i just call `toolbar.bringtoFront()` on my `oncreate` And everything works fine now.